# Flutter- unmask common part using BlendMode.xor

Tags: dart, flutter

there are two images overlap with each other,
I am trying to remove the common part of the image, using BlendMdode.xor
But it is not working. Something showing the different result.

```
var s1 = Size(size.width.toDouble() / 2, size.height.toDouble() / 2);
    rect = Offset(size.width / 3, size.height / 2.30) & new Size(0.0, 0.0);
    _fittedSize = applyBoxFit(boxfit, size * 3.0, size * .9);
    inputSubrect =
        Alignment.center.inscribe(_fittedSize.source, Offset.zero & s1);

outputSubrect = Alignment.center.inscribe(_fittedSize.destination, rect);
if (imagePath != null) {
      p.blendMode = BlendMode.xor;
      canvas.drawImageRect(imagePath1, inputSubrect, outputSubrect, p);
    }
    var s2 = Size(size.width.toDouble() / 2, size.height.toDouble() / 2);

    rect = Offset(size.width / 3, size.height / 1.8) & new Size(0.0, 0.0);
    _fittedSize = applyBoxFit(boxfit, size * 3.0, size * .9);
    inputSubrect =
        Alignment.center.inscribe(_fittedSize.source, Offset.zero & s2);

    outputSubrect = Alignment.center.inscribe(_fittedSize.destination, rect);

    if (imagePath != null) {
      p.blendMode = BlendMode.xor;
      canvas.drawImageRect(imagePath1, inputSubrect, outputSubrect, p);
    }
```

original image:[image]
result i am getting: 
[image]

[image]

I am trying to do this:

Answer (score 0):

Below Code may help to resolve your problem

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new ClipPath(clipper: new PiClipper(),
child: new Container(
  width: 150.0,
  height: 150.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      shape: BoxShape.circle
  ),
),);
}

class PiClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
  var path = Path();
  path.moveTo(0.0, 0.0);
  path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
  path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
  path.lineTo(size.width/2, size.height);
  path.lineTo(size.width/2, size.height/2);
  path.lineTo(0.0, size.height/2);
  path.close();
  return path;
}

@override
bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

[image: above code UI]

Comment: Thanks, but this is just clipping image, I want to remove that overlapping part. and background image should appear. using BlendMode. not clipping just erase that part.

Comment: thanks, finally I did what I was trying to do. Image painter.
Using ``ImageShader``.